# Percentage total changing every time I filter power bi

Tags: filter, powerbi, percentage, calculated-columns

I'm very new to power bi and I'm trying to create a bar graph from a matrix that is calculating a % based on column total. However every time I filter by my slicers, the totals change. How do I fix this please?

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5X53.png)

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVwJA.png)

I've tried this formula but it is not working:

```
Total cost % = SUM('Data 1'[Total cost])/CALCULATE(SUM('Data 1'[Mapped Function]);ALL('Data 1'[Organisation]))
```

I want to be able to filter the graph by the two slicers in the picture so it shows the same percentages shown in the table.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Total cost % =
  DIVIDE(
    SUM('Data 1'[Total cost]),
    CALCULATE( SUM('Data 1'[Total cost]), ALL('Data 1'[Mapped Function]) )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked in calculating the correct % however whenever I try and filter by mapped function, it shows 100% of each category by client instead of the % of the category relative to that client's total @SamNseir

Comment: Updated answer from `ALLSELECTED` to `ALL`

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much that worked.